# How to delete Tkinter widgets from a window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a list of `tkinter` widgets that I want to change dynamically.

How to delete the widgets from the window?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can call [`pack_forget`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_forget-method) to remove a widget (if you use [`pack`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) to add it to the window).

Example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

b = Button(root, text="Delete me", command=lambda: b.pack_forget())
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you use `pack_forget`, you can later show the widget again calling `pack` again. If you want to permanently delete it, call `destroy` on the widget (then you won't be able to re-add it).

If you use the [`grid`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/layout-mgt.html#grid) method, you can use [`grid_forget`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_forget-method) or `grid_remove` to *hide* the widget.

Comment: @TheBeardedBerry: be aware that `pack_forget` doesn't delete widgets, it only removes them from view. They will still exist, potentially causing a memory leak if you keep recreating widgets without destroying them.

Comment: If I `pack_forget` a Frame and then delete it, will it delete the child widgets too, or should I delete them individually?

Comment: can you do something like `place_forget` for place instead of pack?

Comment: @Stegosaurus: Yes, there's also a [`place_forget()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm#Tkinter.Place.place_forget-method) method.

Answer (score 26):

One way you can do it, is to get the slaves list from the frame that needs to be cleared and destroy or "hide" them according to your needs. To get a clear frame you can do it like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def clear():
    list = root.grid_slaves()
    for l in list:
        l.destroy()

Label(root,text='Hello World!').grid(row=0)
Button(root,text='Clear',command=clear).grid(row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

You should call `grid_slaves()`, `pack_slaves()` or `slaves()` depending on the method you used to add the widget to the frame.

Comment: I had 5 buttons in a window. Then I needed to add 3 new buttons and remove old buttons. But 2 old buttons were on the window. With this solution all 5 buttons are removed and only 3 new buttons are added. I use MVP pattern for my app.

Comment: In the for loop you will need to treat who gets to be deleted and who gets to be removed.

Answer (score 5):

You simply use the `destroy()` method to delete the specified widgets like this:

```
lbl = tk.Label(....)

btn = tk.Button(....., command=lambda: lbl.destroy())
```

Using this you can completely destroy the specific widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you have a list of widgets to change dynamically. Do you want to reuse and reconfigure existing widgets, or create all new widgets and delete the old ones? It affects the answer.

If you want to reuse the existing widgets, just reconfigure them. Or, if you just want to hide some of them temporarily, use the corresponding "forget" method to hide them. If you mapped them with `pack()` calls, you would hide with `pack_forget()` (or just `forget()`) calls. Accordingly, `grid_forget()` to hide gridded widgets, and `place_forget()` for placed widgets.

If you do not intend to reuse the widgets, you can destroy them with a straight `destroy()` call, like `widget.destroy()`, to free up resources.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
clear_btm=Button(master,text="Clear") #this button will delete the widgets 
clear_btm["command"] = lambda one = button1, two = text1, three = entry1: clear(one,two,three) #pass the widgets
clear_btm.pack()

def clear(*widgets):
    for widget in widgets:
        widget.destroy() #finally we are deleting the widgets.
```

Comment: Please add some context or comments to your code so that the author and others can make sense of it easily

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function if you want to remove widgets based on row and col indexes. Please note that you can choose the method `_forget()` method based on the layout manager you used.

```py
def remove_widgets_based_on_location(master, rows, cols):
    # list widgets to be removed
    widgets = []
    for row in rows:
        for col in cols:
            l = master.grid_slaves(row, col)
            for i in l:
                widgets.append(i)

    # remove widgets
    for widget in widgets:
        widget.grid_forget()
        # widget.pack_forget()
        # widget.place_forget()
```

For example, if you want to remove the widgets from the `root` frame on the frist three rows and first two columns:

```py
remove_widgets_based_on_location(master = root,
                                 rows = [0, 1, 2],
                                 cols = [0, 1])
```

Answer (score -1):

Today I learn some simple and good click event handling using tkinter gui library in python3, which I would like to share inside this thread.

```
from tkinter import *

cnt = 0


def MsgClick(event):
    children = root.winfo_children()
    for child in children:
        # print("type of widget is : " + str(type(child)))
        if str(type(child)) == "<class 'tkinter.Message'>":
            # print("Here Message widget will destroy")
            child.destroy()
            return

def MsgMotion(event):
  print("Mouse position: (%s %s)" % (event.x, event.y))
  return


def ButtonClick(event):
    global cnt, msg
    cnt += 1
    msg = Message(root, text="you just clicked the button..." + str(cnt) + "...time...")
    msg.config(bg='lightgreen', font=('times', 24, 'italic'))
    msg.bind("<Button-1>", MsgClick)
    msg.bind("<Motion>", MsgMotion)
    msg.pack()
    #print(type(msg)) tkinter.Message


def ButtonDoubleClick(event):
    import sys; sys.exit()


root = Tk()

root.title("My First GUI App in Python")
root.minsize(width=300, height=300)
root.maxsize(width=400, height=350)
button = Button(
    root, text="Click Me!", width=40, height=3
)
button.pack()
button.bind("<Button-1>", ButtonClick)
button.bind("<Double-1>", ButtonDoubleClick)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope it will help someone...

Comment: is this supposed to be an answer to the question? If not, please remove it. If so, you need to clarify how this relates to deleting a widget.

Comment: Your code does not answer the question though. You can't just post random things in a thread, because that's not what the thread is for.

Answer (score -1):

You can use forget method on the widget

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

b = Button(root, text="Delete me", command=b.forget)
b.pack()

b['command'] = b.forget

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This will raise an error because `b` isn't defined.

Answer (score -2):

I found that when the widget is part of a function and the `grid_remove` is part of another function it does not remove the label. In this example...

```
def somefunction(self):
    Label(self, text=" ").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    self.text_ent = Entry(self)
    self.text_ent.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
def someotherfunction(self):
    somefunction.text_ent.grid_remove()
```

...there is no valid way of removing the Label.

The only solution I could find is to give the label a name and make it global:

```
def somefunction(self):
    global label
    label = Label(self, text=" ")
    label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    self.text_ent = Entry(self)
    self.text_ent.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
def someotherfunction(self):
    global label
    somefunction.text_ent.grid_remove()
    label.grid_remove()
```

When I ran into this problem there was a class involved, one function being in the class and one not, so I'm not sure the `global label` lines are really needed in the above.

Comment: The fact that there is no way to remove the first label you create isn't related to the fact you're creating it in one function and removing it in another, it's simply that you're failing to hold on to a reference. This isn't a tkinter thing, it's a programming thing -- to act on an object you must have a reference to the object. In your second example you don't need to use a global variable. Instead, assign it to `self` just like you do the entry widget.