# How do you check for which mouse button was clicked in python tkinter application?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to detect whether left or right mouse was clicked on a tkinter button.

Comment: There are B1,B2,B3 check https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148471/on-python-how-do-i-determine-which-button-was-clicked/425411180) help you

Comment: A button only gets activated only wen u right-click, unless you want the function to be called by using a `bind`

Comment: @CoolCloud: _"A button only gets activated only wen u right-click"_ is not a true statement.

Comment: @BryanOakley GOD, im so foolish, i meant left click. My bad

Comment: @CoolCloud: even then it's not true. You can get buttons events for any time of click - left, right, middle, etc.

Comment: @BryanOakley i meant the original effect, bruh. without binding or event, the button will be clicked by left click. Thats whatt i meant

Answer (score 2):

You can bind `<Any-Button>` and check which button is clicked in the callback.

Below is a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_click(event):
    if event.num == 1:
        print('Left button clicked')
    elif event.num == 3:
        print('Right button clicked')

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Click Me')
btn.pack()
btn.bind('<Any-Button>', on_click)

root.mainloop()
```