# Python GUI CheckBox

Tags: python, checkbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elVgS.png)

I have to do checkboxes and when I tap delete it Should delete the checks can someone help?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989858/15160601

Comment: Please put your code in the question.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)