# How do I remove all elements in a tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am currectly building a Tkinter GUI using Python, and I want to see how I can remove all elements, creating a blank clean slate. I tried .destroy(), but that completely exits out the window. How do I do this?

Example code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
mylabel = tk.Label(root, text='I want this to be removed')
mylabel.pack()
#I want to remove the mylabel Label.
```

Comment: You used pack so you can use unpack to remove the elements. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364981/how-to-delete-tkinter-widgets-from-a-window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either remove or destroy all children of the root iteratively (eg: `for child in root.winfo_children(): child.destroy()`), or you can create a single frame directly in the root and make all other widgets children of that frame, and then just remove or delete the frame.

Comment: I'm new to this and I even created an alt to avoid downvotes on my main acc :(, but does children refer to each object (label, button, etc)?

Comment: @dinosauce34: you should not be creating more than one account. If you don't want downvotes, write better questions. Yes, "children" refers to the individual widgets.

Comment: Is there a way to do this while the GUI is running? When I run the for loop while the GUI is running, I get this error:
for child in root.winfo_children:
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

Comment: @dinosauce34 _"Is there a way to do this while the GUI is running?"_ - well, you certainly can't do it if it's _not_ running.  You have to _call_ the method - `root.winfo_children()`.