After the new windows update my tkinter application gives me error when I try to run the exe
I've developed a program for some Excel automations. Recently, a friend of mine began encountering errors with it following a Windows 10 update. Strangely, on my computer and another, the program functions perfectly without any hitches. The error message he receives is as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ttkbootstrap\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ttkbootstrap\widgets.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ttkbootstrap\dialogs\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ttkbootstrap\dialogs\dialogs.py", line 536, in <module>
  File "ttkbootstrap\dialogs\dialogs.py", line 566, in DatePickerDialog
  File "locale.py", line 615, in setlocale
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting


Despite searching the internet for solutions, none have proven effective. Attempts included manually configuring the locale with code and updating libraries, as well as obtaining alternative builds. Regrettably, none of these endeavors have resolved the issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I think you need to reinstall tkinter here is how to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364981/how-to-delete-tkinter-widgets-from-a-window

@StudyFlow This link doesn't look like guide to reinstalling tkinter

I don't think it is because of tkinter. Since I can run the program in multiple devices whiteout any problem. It says unsupported locale setting so maybe it is because of the language stings in his computer. I don't have any idea.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
